# symfony2 "find" is not finding all results in db

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.7

In a project I am working on at the moment is not finding the part number in the database
its using symfony 2.7 and doctrine. Ive tried find, findBy, findOneBy, and findAll still none of them is able to find the correct part number that is in the database.

This is supposed to search the database and find like part numbers and display it on the page. Going through to process is as follows.

1.The user uploads an invoice by copying and pasting from an excel file using the
[Site form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzpCy.png)

2. Then the information is grabbed and the items are put placed into an array.

   ```
    if ($import) {
        $importData = $form->get('importData')->getData();
        /* @var $invoice OnWaterInvoice */
        $pattern = '/"(.+)\r\n?(.+)"/';
        $replace = '$1$2';
        $importData = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $importData);
        $importData = explode("\r\n", $importData);
        foreach ($importData as $item) {
            $item = trim($item);
            $item = explode("\t", $item);
            foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
                $value = trim($value);
                if ($key == 0 || $key == 4) {
                    $value = (int) $value;
                }
                if ($key == 5 || $key == 6) {
                    $value = (float) $value;
                }
                $item[$key] = $value;
            }
   ```
3. This is where I am having issue is this line of code right here

   `$pn = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('EICStockBundle:PartNumber')->find($item[2]); $invoiceItem->setPartNumber($pn);`

This doesn't grab the part number even though it is in the database. Its as though the values aren't updating. Because if a new number is added I get the same result. It skips it.
the part number is the id of the table however when I use
`->findBy('id'=>$item[2])` I get an error.

This is supposed to find the part as well as possible parts because sometimes the incorrect part number is used. If I could get some pointers on what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

**UPDATE ----**

Ive tried clearing the doctrine cache
using

`doctrine:cache:clear-collection-region doctrine:cache:clear-entity-region doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`

I've also tried to schema:rebuild and Update but still hasn't pull the correct id

Comment: have you tried `->findBy(['id' => $item[2]])` - because findby requires an array, and what you posted there isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($key == 5 || $key == 6) {
    $value = (float) $value;
}
```

You are trying to find a database entry via ID, which is in this case a float number and in other cases an integer. I think (and strongly recommend) that your ID is not a float but an integer. So this could be the potential problem - both for doctrine and for MySQL.

What error are you getting, if you use the following?

```
->findBy(['id' => $item[2]])
```

Another potential problem could be the following line. Here you are overwriting the looped array:

```
foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
  //....
  $item[$key] = $value;
```

Is this done on purpose?

Have you done a `var_dump($item)` before you are executing the `find()` method to see if the values are correctly?

PS: Are you using Symfony 2.7 for a specific reason? Symfony 5.4 is the LTS now, so we are 3 major version ahead right now.

Comment: This project was inherited from my manager who doesn't work at my job anymore and I just started learning :/ php. So I never knew about var_dumb() So I'm not aware on how to troubleshoot these things properly other than purposely breaking it to find out what its doing. I can't even access the dev server. Tried adding the var_dump($item) before the find() and it just breaks. I get an error 500 on the screen. Anyway to add it to a file?

Comment: Also an update to symfony may break the current site completely

Comment: I forgot to mention in my reply this was set up before I had any say in it. I'm not entirely sure why he was using a float when the database id is a varchar(15) and a primary key. If there is a better way to split the data received. I haven't been able to figure out what it is completely doing.